# Is there a formula for probability of how much sampled mean deviates from true mean?

Tags: probability

Is there a formula that provides an upper bound on the probability that the empirical mean after $n$ i.i.d. samples equate something? Say we are drawing from a bowl with a true mean of $b$, and after drawing $n$ samples, the average of the draws $\hat{b}$ can be represented as $|\hat{b}| = b + d$ whereas d $d$ is the amount that the empirical mean deviates from its expectation. Is there a way to establish an upper bound for the probability based on the value of $d$? I have used Hoeffding's inequality as $Pr[\hat{b} \ge b + d]$ includes the scenario of $\Pr[\hat{b} = b + d]$, but then this bound becomes obviously very conservative. I am interested in whether there exists a way to establish a tighter bound? Any insightful thoughts will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be interested in the class of [concentration inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_inequality)

Answer (score 1):

This is the essence of the [sampling distribution of the mean](https://bolt.mph.ufl.edu/6050-6052/module-9/sampling-distribution-of-x-bar/)

What you are trying to get is what neighborhood around a calculated sample mean is highly likely to contain the true mean. This is the motivation for the confidence interval.